# ConstraintLayout: Minimal distance to edge with wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I have e.g. a Textview in a Constraint Layout, which I want to be as small as the text is (wrap content):

[image]

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
        android:text="This is an example Message."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But I want to define a minimal distance to the right edge of the screen. So if the text gets larger it currently looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

How do I do that?

Edit:

I still have no clue. 
One deleted answer suggested to try setting
    android:layout_marginRight 
and 
    android:layout_marginEnd

I tried using padding to, but with no success.

Comment: Are you using this version `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha6'` if not then Try with it ??

Comment: What should I try with it? I have no approach yet

Comment: Do you want to place this in center? or in left side? How much screen size in terms of width, you want it to cover?

Comment: I want it to stay on the left side and have the size of the text if the text is short enough (first picture). Otherwise I want it just not to fill up the whole screen (so not picture 2)  and have a little space on the right side (picture 3). See the attached pictures, I hope my concern gets clear.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but it might help others looking at this.

Try adding these lines to the TextView

```
android:maxWidth="200dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```